# Error deleting character in summernote only in google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, summernote

**Code Summernote HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
         <div id="optionContext">
             <label for="InputText">{% trans "Crie um contexto da oportunidade" %}</label>
               <textarea id="summernote" name="editordata" >
                </textarea>
          </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

**Code Summernote JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#summernote').summernote({
        callbacks: {
            onPaste: function (e) {
                var bufferText = ((e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('Text');
                e.preventDefault();
                document.execCommand('insertText', false, bufferText);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

> I checked that this only happens when I delete text by going up the line in google chrome browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error in code above summernote, I missed close tags